# Type error after renaming Pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, rename, typeerror

Problem description: I have two dataframes ('Train' and 'Test') with nearly identical columns('Test' has two variables that don't appear in Train, and Train has one variable that doesn't appear in Test; however, to produce "Test", I needed to do some processing in R, because I couldn't figure out how to do the equivalent of PLYR's full join in Pandas.  The end result was that all spaces and apostrophes were replaced with periods in the R dataframe names in Test.

My current problem is that I need to have identical variable names in both dataframes(minus the extra one in Test).  My current attempt is the following:

```
Test.columns[2:]=Train.columns[1:]
After index points 2 and 1, columns are the same
```

This appears to nominally work;  when I enter

```
Test.columns
```

I get the expected output. However, problems come up later.  I'm trying to delete a column in Train if a condition is met, and the same column in Test.

```
for i in Train.columns[1:]:
     if condition:
        del Train[i]
        del Test[i]
```

Which produces

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I get the same error if I just put in

```
Test
```

but get the expected output if I put in something like

```
Test['varname']
```

I suppose I was hoping someone would immediately recognize whatever grave sin I committed in my column name reassignment that is generating the type error (I have no problem if I'm just deleting from Train), or suggest an alternative way to change the column names.

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I thought perhaps the sin is changing the thing which you are iterating over whilst iterating over it, always a dangerous game. However I can't reproduce this in 0.12 (which version of pandas are you using?).

Comment: Could you post an example which demonstrates this problem i.e. with some dummy data? Presumably a DataFrames with one row (but with your columns) would be enough to show this behaviour? (it *may* be fixed by upgrading, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a function, e.g. to replace apostrophes and spaces with `.`:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["don't", "no way"])

In [12]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace("'", '.').replace(' ', '.'))
Out[12]: 
   don.t  no.way
0      1       2
1      3       4
```

*It's preferable to not have to use R here...

perhaps it's worth asking another question on how to do a PLYR's style full-join? :)*

Comment: is a full-join different from an outer join `(df1.join(df2, how='outer')` ?

Comment: They seem to be.  Thank you for your suggestion; it effectively solves my problem.